# Uploading products through xml on ebay

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I have a problem uploading products through xml on ebay.

I use the function AddFixedPriceItem for upload and it returns the following error:

> 5013 String Value is Too Long (Item specifics: tagName).
>   String Value for "TagName" is Too Long and will be removed from item specifics. Maxinum lenght is "40".

What can I look inside my xml file?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your issue is that value your are providing for TagName is too long. It cannot exceed 40 characters.

Search your XML for `<Name>` and make sure that the value inside of `<Name></Name>` is less than 40 characters.

```
 <ItemSpecifics> 
  <NameValueList> 
    <Name> string </Name> // <--- This is what you are searching for. The value within must be less than 40 characters.
    <Value> string </Value>
  </NameValueList>
</ItemSpecifics>
```